# Push to huggingface from server

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper

I trained my `ASR-model` based on `openai/whisper-medium` and I want to push the model and all things I need to upload into `huggingface` **private-repo** from my server, I'm not using `notebook` or `colab`.

this is my training part

```
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-medium")

model.config.forced_decoder_ids = None
model.config.suppress_tokens = []

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="/home/model/whisper",
    per_device_train_batch_size=20,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1, 
    learning_rate=3e-5,
    warmup_steps=500,
    max_steps=1000,
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    fp16=True,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    generation_max_length=225,
    save_steps=1000,
    eval_steps=1000,
    logging_steps=25,
    report_to=["tensorboard"],
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="wer",
    greater_is_better=False,
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    args=training_args,
    model=model,
    train_dataset=common_voice["train"],
    eval_dataset=common_voice["test"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=processor.feature_extractor,
)

processor.save_pretrained("/home/model/tmp_whisper")

trainer.train()

model.save_pretrained("/home/model/tmp_whisper")
```

Comment: What is the error here? Or are you asking about documentation to use push to hub?